# GarbageCollectorMXBean Full GC CollectionCount and CollectionTime

Tags: java, garbage-collection, visualvm

I used GarbageCollectorMXBean to get the JVM Full GC CollectionCount
and CollectionTime. But the data is not equal with data that is
collected by the jstat(but VisualVM 's data equal with jstat).

So,I check out VisualVM source code to study how it works and have seen that
VisualVM also works through GarbageCollectorMXBean to collect JVM full GC
data .
 Why?

I add gc log for for java application(parts of  JVM parameter is  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -verbose:GC -Xloggc:/home/yubaofu/work/debug/gc.log). I read the gc log  and have seen that the full gc CollectionCount is not equal to the data that jstat displays. Does this mean that jstat full gc is not only full gc  ?

visualVm vs jstat 

 visualVm full gc is 4 

 jstat is full gc also 4

[image]

jconsole vs jstat 

jconsole full gc is 2

  jstat full gc is 4

[image]

why then not equal?

gc log vs jstat 

 gc log full gc is 2

 jstat full gc is 4
 [image]

I am sorry for my poor english, hope you can understand what i mean :)

Comment: I have found the same descrepancy and decided it didn't matter in the end, but it is curious.

Comment: The javadoc for GarbageCollectorMXBean.getCollectionCount says it returns "Returns the total number of collections that have occurred." and does not mention full only (so will return other, non-full collections too). Would this explain the difference?

Comment: @Disco3 yes ,but every gc name has GarbageCollectorMXBean.so GarbageCollectorMXBean only return the representative gc name is total number of collections that have occurred,not total number collections that have occurred.

Comment: VisualGc is plug of VisualVM,where is the source code of VisualGC.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are comparing data that represent different things.

First, GarbageCollectorMXBean.getCollectionCount returns the "total number of collections that have occurred" for a given GC. This mean that you will get the total number of Young GC and Old GC, not necessarily the number of Full GC. Especially if you are using CMS.

You are grepping CMS-initial-mark, which is definitely not a Full GC. A full GC in your case would be a call to `System.gc()`, a ParNew Promotion failure or a Concurrent Mode Failure. Otherwise, you are just looking a the number of CMS cycles.

Finally, I think VisualVM use the SA agent to get more information, whereas JConsole uses only MX Beans. So you won't get the same data.

Comment: The "total number of collections that have occurred", over what time period is that? Is it since the startup of the JVM?